# Cucumber No features found with JUnit5

Tags: cucumber, junit5, cucumber-junit

I am trying to setup Cucumber in my project. I am following the same configuration from my previous projects but I still have issues with running the tests. Now I am starting to suspect that the issue might be that this project is using JUnit 5 instead of 4. I have added junit4 to the build options as well to be able to execute the @RunWith annotation with jUnit4, but I still get the same error ( No features found at classpath ) .
The runner class is as follows:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions.SnippetType;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:resources", plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/reports/cucumber/html",
"json:target/cucumber.json", "usage:target/usage.jsonx",
"junit:target/junit.xml"}, snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE)
public class TestCucumberRunner {

}
```

The structure of the folders is following:

[image]

Here is the pom configuration:

[image]

As far as I can see, the @RunWith annotation is imported from junit4 and not 5, so why is this issue happening?
I also tried adding the feature file in the same folder with the runner, as well as adding the exact path in the feature option, but still the same error.

Answer (score 4):

With Junit5, you just need to write runner like below :

```
@Suite
@SelectClasspathResource("Features Folder")
public class Runner {

}
```

For using tags, you can put the tags properties in junit-platform.properties.

You can refer for pom dependencies - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/pom.xml

I was facing a lot of issues. I followed above and could run my cucumber tests with Junit5 without any issues.

Comment: The pom has moved - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/maven/pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

You can run Cucumber tests with Junit 5 and via maven. I searched a lot before finding the right configuration.

The important steps :

- add maven-surefire-plugin in you plugins pom, so cucumber tests can bu run from `mvn test`
- use the same structure for features in your test resources as your cucumber java steps (if your test class is in com.example.usescase, locate your feature in resources/com/example/usecase )
- add cucumber launcher on the root folder of your java tests. I can be annotated with just `@Cucumber`

Courtesy to https://github.com/bonigarcia , I really found how to make it work thanks to its repository https://github.com/bonigarcia/mastering-junit5/tree/master/junit5-cucumber

Comment: please note, the referred project includes gradle script as well (for inspiration)

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problems with the step definitions as well (cann't tell exactly by looking at the info), looks like that Cucumber cannot find your feature file step definitions.

please have a look on [cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/)

You need to specify the path to your step definitions (glue path) correctly.

Usually cucumber jvm will search in the package (or sub-packages) of the runner class. However, you can also mention explicitly by the following way:

> @CucumberOptions(glue = ["", "", ""])

Comment: This is from official Cucumber documentation:

By default, when using classpath:, Cucumber starts looking in the root of you classpath.
If you configure Cucumber to search in "classpath:features", you can put your features in src/test/resources/features

I tried adding the glue option, then I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The glue path contained invalid identifiers C:/Users/user/project/src/test/resources/features

Comment: Sounds like you already know what is wrong with your feature path.

Comment: I think this information applies to JUnit 4, not JUnit 5.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Cucumber with JUnit 5 has not been documented very well (yet). The trick is to use the `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` as described in https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/.

For example:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <configurationParameters>
                        cucumber.plugin=pretty,html:target/site/cucumber-pretty.html
                        cucumber.publish.quiet=true
                        cucumber.publish.enabled=false
                    </configurationParameters>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now use the `maven-surefire-plugin` to inject Cucumber parameters, since the 'old' JUnit 4 `@CucumberOptions` annotation won't have any effect anymore.
More Cucumber configuration options can be found here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options

Your Java entry point for your Cucumber tests will now look like this:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class BDDEntryPointTest {
    /*
    Entry point class for Cucumber test.
    It will automatically scan for
        1. *.feature files in src/test/resources
        2. Step definitions in java files under in src/test/java
    */
}
```

Comment: I also had this issue sometime ago. I solved it by adding cucumber configurations (`cucumber.features, cucumber.publish.quiet, cucumber.plugin, etc.`) to `src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties` instead of adding them to `pom.xml`.

Comment: this makes no sense. You present your answer with `junit-5` and then show `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with `junit5` and I got it resolved by removing these three dependencies from `pom`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

and by keeping these ones

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and then your runner class will be just

```
@Cucumber
public class AcceptanceIT {
}
```

and step defs would be . No `@Test` annotations

```
  @Given("I log {string}")
        public void logSomething(String teststr )   {
            System.out.println("sample text:"+ teststr);
       }
```

**Note**  I am using `maven-failsafe` here . The runner class name might different if you use other plugin like `maven-surefire` or use any other mechanism. Here is my `maven-failsafe` config

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>integration-test</id> 
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  
                </goals>
              </execution>
             <execution>
                <id>verify</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>  
            </executions>
              <configuration>
               
                <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
   <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory> 
            
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
       
                </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you might not have all the dependencies of junit-platform in my case i had to add each one of them individually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```